# hotkey for editing init.el / .emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm a bloody beginner with lisp, so please bear with me.

I figure the best way to lean is to dive in. Because I'm setting up my Emacs environment, I'll edit my `init.el` often, I wanted to add a hotkey to find it for editing quickly, as I'll need it often in the course of the next weeks.

I tried:

```
(global-set-key [f7] '(find-file "~/.emacs.d/init.el"))
```

to no avail, the answer when pressing  the next time is:

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, (find-file "~/.emacs.d/init.el")
```

I also tried to put it into an own func, mimicking a working hotkey (for deft `(global-set-key [f8] 'deft)`):

```
(defun sz-init-el ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file "~/.emacs.d/init.el"))
(global-set-key [f7] 'sz-init-el)
```

That worked. So I tried adding `(interactive)` to my first trial:

```
(global-set-key [f7] '((interactive) (find-file "~/.emacs.d/init.el")))
```

But that would not work (again: `Wrong type argument: commandp, ...`).

So, is there a way to set a global key binding without defining a function/command first? Or do I have to go via the `defun` detour?

Thank you for your help and answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a lambda (aka anonymous function):

```
(global-set-key [f7] (lambda () (interactive) (find-file user-init-file)))
```

Also, use of variable `user-init-file` is preferred over hardcoding the name.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense (I know lambdas from python). -- particular thanks for the `user-init-file` pointer!

Comment: Saying "I know lambdas from python" to lispers is like saying "I know wings from penguins" to seagulls. :-)

Comment: @sds: I just meant that I have a basic grasp of anonymous functions, and that while not necessarily immediately clear why it'd be necessary (without knowing elisp's syntax better), I understand the syntax and don't need further clarifications what a lambda is. But I get your point.

Comment: FYI, it's almost always best to *not* quote lambda expressions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948325/why-not-quoting-lambda