# Emacs: How to enable highlighting breakpoints in a text terminal (emacs -nw)

Tags: debugging, emacs, breakpoints

Emacs doesn't show breakpoints in text mode. 
I tried integrating the suggestions [here](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/issues/702) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262427/emacs-key-binding-for-multiple-commands), but failed (I am not a lisp programmer).

I tried:

```
(require 'gdb-mi)
(setq default-text-properties '(foo 1111))

(defun set_breakpt_cmds ()
  "set breakpoint and indicate on editor"
  (interactive)
  (gud-break)
  (gdb-put-breakpoint-icon "false" (get-text-property 1 'foo)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'set_breakpt_cmds)
```

The resulting error is

`Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (arg) "Set breakpoint at current line." (interactive "p") (if (not gud-running) (gud-call "dbstop \
at %l in %f" arg))), 0`

Note: A similar issue is [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3711/highlight-breakpoints-with-pdb) (following [this](https://gist.github.com/rocky/7d773de32be146eb7292)). However the solution there doesn't fit me because I would like to be able to call the fix from `.emacs` file. This way it is easier to duplicate my emacs configuration when I setup a new linux box.

Thanks

Comment: `text mode` for me, is the major mode used when you edit files thatr contain just random text (e.g. with extension `.txt`),  I think what you mean is `inside a text terminal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get comes from the fact that `gud-break` expects an argument (which isn't used), so just use `(gud-break 1)`.

The message reads as follow:

- the error is of kind `wrong number of arguments`
- when calling `(lambda (arg) ...)` (where we see that exactly one argument is expected)
- and it was called with `0` arguments.